# Package for magento connect 1.0 and 2.0

Tags: magento

When submitting my package to magento connect I'm getting a rejection with the following message:

> Extension Packaging: Repackage your extension correctly so that
>   compatible Community Editions and/or Enterprise Editions correspond
>   with correct channels. (Magento Connect 1.0 and Magento Connect 2.0).
>   DO NOT resubmit as a new extension. It will be rejected and deleted
>   from your account. Repackage and resubmit as instructed in the
>   guideline

I packed my extension using the built-in extension packager on magento 1.7 and I marked  "1.5 and later" and  "Pre 1.5" both.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roy, packager creates 2 different packages in var/connect/ and var/pear/. The first package is   Magento Connect 2.0 version, the second one - 1.0 version.

The trick is that you should upload version for magento connect 1.0 from var/pear/ and it will be automatically converted to the 2.0 version

Comment: But wouldn't that make it available for pre 1.5 versions, which we might not even want to support cuz it might not even work at all?

Comment: you can specify magento vesions before uploading package

Comment: I chose only the "1.5 & later" option, and all I got was a single package under `var/connect/`. Nothing inside the `var/pear/`. I am interested in trying this out as I am having some issues with Magento uploader - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729787/error-on-uploading-magento-extension

Answer (score 2):

Magento has a set of guides on how to write, package extension and design your profile http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/

The link to Magento Connect Packing Extension Guidelines file is below:
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf