# Error on uploading Magento extension

Tags: magento

After several attempts I have succeed to packaged one extension by using instructions from this PDF - http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

Everything looks good, but when I try to upload the extension, it throws an error, saying that the filename should be in the format `XXXXXX-1.0.0` format without the extension, where xxxxxxxxx is my form key, but when I try to upload the renamed copy of the packaged file (one that Magento connect manager extension generated), it throws these 2 errors:

> An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect 1.0: Unable
>   to upload new release `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-1.0.0.tgz`
>
> An error occurred
>   during upload to channel MagentoConnect 2.0: Package
>   `AnattaDesign_AbandonedCarts` not found

I did a bit of research on the error and got to know this has been an issue with Magento in the past and people were facing the exact same issue. On some of them, I found @rondata replying back who was the community manager in back those days, but not sure if he still is.

So any clue how can I get this issue resolved? Whether it could also be an issue with how I packaged the extension? Or may be who is the current community manager and where can I seek some escalation on their uploader bug?

Comment: Do you use packager? If so this could probably helphttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468595/package-for-magento-connect-1-0-and-2-0/12469301

Comment: Yep! The link you have sent me takes me back to the link I have in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I know what the reason is. When you are asked for the extension key when creating a new extension on `magentocommerce.com`, don't add the form key over there as your extension key. It's meant to be something unique like `Namespace_Module`.

When you do that, the error should go away and you should be all good!